# Can the path of `import` statement contain multiple `/`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have two files in one directory, `sum.mjs` and `main.mjs`.

The content of `sum.mjs` is:

```js
const sum = (a, b) => a + b;

export { sum };
```

And the `main.mjs` is:

```js
// import { sum } from './add.mjs';
import { sum } from './////////add.mjs';

console.log(sum(1, 1));
```

I find this code can work, it can output the result `2` by run `node main.mjs`. So can the path of the `import` statement contain multiple `/`?

In addition, I found `import { sum } from './///\\\\\\\/////add.mjs';` can work well too, it's amazing.

Can someone explain this and why is this happening?

**Environment**: node 15.2.1 on macOS

Comment: If you tested it yourself, then I guess the answer would have to be "yes", it can contain multiple slashes.  I assume this is dependant on the webserver providing the JS files whether it handles the slashes the way it does here.

Comment: @Matthew I ran this code on node v15.2.1. I am very curious about this phenomenon. If you say it is related to the local webserver, how can I verify it, or where there is related documentation.

Comment: An `import` statement can contain *any* arbitrary string literal value and will be syntactically valid in ES6. Whether it actually is allowed and will resolve to a module depends very much on your environment. Please add the build pipeline and execution engine you use to your question.

Comment: So you're using [native node esm](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html), no transpiler?

Comment: Yeah, I did not use any transpiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For POSIX systems see [Pathname](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_271)

> Multiple successive `<slash>` characters are considered to be the same as one `<slash>`,

Not sure how windows would handle it.

---

Also, depending on what is used internally in Node, see [`path.normalize(path)`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_path)

> When multiple, sequential path segment separation characters are found (e.g. / on POSIX and either \ or / on Windows), they are replaced by a single instance of the platform-specific path segment separator (/ on POSIX and \ on Windows). Trailing separators are preserved.